Edge - change available colors for tab groups
As you may know, Edge has a feature to create tab groups. Each tab group can contain n tabs.

According to this question "How to change the tab group colours?" there is no official option to change the colors.
On my Windows 10 only these colors are available:

Is there an unofficial way / a heck to change the colors that are available?
